# Angularjs DatePicker daypickerDirective

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I try to customize my datepicker by following this :
https://productblog.townscript.com/customizing-angular-ui-bootstrap-directives-c4461c12afa9#.hfvv6e2il

On theses lines of code :

```
$provide.decorator('daypickerDirective', function ($delegate) {        
    var directive = $delegate[0];
    directive.templateUrl = "custom-template/datepicker/day.html";
    return $delegate;
});
```

I've this error :

> Unknown provider: daypickerDirectiveProvider

Note : I'm a newbie :/

Any idea ?

**Update 1**
http://plnkr.co/edit/1IJtST5eGrWVipLip7hX

Comment: Can you provide a larger sample of code? There isn't much in the snippet you provided to help diagnose the issue.

Comment: On plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/1IJtST5eGrWVipLip7hX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I've found the solution :
https://github.com/spongessuck/gm.datepickerMultiSelect/issues/28

> The v1.0.6 doesn't support it, because you are decorating
>   daypickerDirective and not the new uibDaypickerDirective.